# Como puedo hacer este estilo en Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, ccs

Lo que quiero hacer es este estilo, con boostrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque finalemente he buscado e intentado y solo consigo este estilo, como puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si agregas el código HTML y CSS de lo que hayas intentado, podríamos ayudarte. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: has provado poniendole al div que quieres que ocupe las 2 filas ponerle un height:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo logre, con el uso de columnas anidadas
esta es la estructura

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```